# What are the rest api's for the Magento2 modules

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.6

We are working on Magento2.2.6 website.

We are planning to build the mobile application. For this, we need the **Rest api's** for the following :

1. Sort by options api
2. Layer navigation
3. Login with otp api's
4. Re-order
5. Product Reviews
6. Product Rating
7. Wishlist api's
8. Social Logins
9. Buy now api's
10. Pin code Validation at check availability

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information you need here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html

Comment: I have already checked this but I didnt get my requirements.